Triangular inequality on the angles of the faces of a trihedron
I just saw this theorem which I'm trying to prove but got stuck.
Given a trihedron like the one below, whose angles between its edges are $\widehat{bc}, \widehat{ac}$ and $\widehat{ab}$, then prove that $\widehat{bc} < \widehat{ac}+ \widehat{ab} $.

I made a plane cut this trihedron in a triangle $ABC$ whose sides are $a,b$ and $c$,
then I put all the lateral faces of this tetrahedron $VABC$ in a plane making three adjacent triangles $\triangle BVC, \triangle CVA$ and $\triangle AVB'$ (with $VB'=VB$). I tried this:
I assumed $\angle AVB' = \widehat{ab}$ is the greater from the three $(\widehat{bc} , \widehat{ac} , \widehat{ab}) $ and I produced the ray $VX$ (inside the interior of $\triangle AVB'$) with $\angle AVX = \widehat{ac}$ and $X \in AB'$.
We have three options: $VX = VC \implies AX = AC = b$ so if $\angle XVB' \ge \widehat{bc}$, we would have $XB' \ge BC = a \implies c \ge a+b$ contradicting the triangle inequality on $\triangle ABC$, so if $VX = VC$, we must have $\widehat{bc} < \widehat{ac}+ \widehat{ab}$.
second option: $VX > VC$, then we take $Y \in \overline{VX}$ such that $VY = VC$, then $AY = b$ from which we can easily see that $AX < AY$ and my goal was to say $AX> b$ and $CX > a$ but I didn't manage to get to this point. Does anyone know an easier way?

Intuitively, cut this net out from paper with $c$ appearing twice, to the left of $a$ and again to the right of $b$, all meeting at $V$ with the desired angles. To make the trihedron you need to fold on $a$ and $b$ to get the two $c$s to match, with the effect of folding that the combination of  $\widehat{ac}$ and $\widehat{ab}$ to give $\widehat{bc}$ must be less than $\widehat{ac}+ \widehat{ab}$.

This was discussed several times on MSE and different proofs were given.

@MoisheKohan I was looking for a more synthetic proof of it, not so much trigonometry and matrices and determinants

You should revise your question to reflect this. Check the synthetic proof given here. There is also a proof using lengths of paths on the sphere.
